# Slide animation between Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-pageradapter

I need to create slide functionality for app using `TabLayout` and `PagerAdapter`. But `PagerAdapter` use `Fragments` for its functionality. But each `Tab` is custom made object with its own lifecycle. Is it possible to add these objects into `PagerAdapter`?

Comment: "But PagerAdapter use Fragments for its functionality." – The `Fragment*PagerAdapter`s use `Fragment`s. `PagerAdapter` itself does not require `Fragment`s, though I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "Slide animation between Activities".

Comment: I want to slide between two pages, but page is not Fragment but custom object with its own lifecycle(not Activity, but Object running in its own thread)

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, `PagerAdapter` does not require `Fragment`s. You can have a look at [its docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/PagerAdapter) to see that none of its methods require or use `Fragment`s. As long as your "custom object"s have a `View` to stick in the `ViewPager`, then I'd imagine you should be able to use it.